# Maximize the distance of pair points within a unit circle

Tags: optimization, uniform-distribution

given a unit circle and N points, how should I scatter these points inside the circle to obtain a maximum pairwise distance? i.e., the average distance (euclidean) between each pair of points will be maximal.

I guess that the answer is some uniform circular distribution, however, I can't generate one..

For 1D it's just np.arange(min_x, max_x, dx)
But for 2D? What should be the dRadius and dTheta? Because with every increase in R I can place more points..

Comment: Using the complex circle, it's just points of the form $$e^{\frac{ki\theta}n},\;k\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: Instead of the *average* pairwise distance, you may want to maximize the *minimum* pairwise distance. This gives you something more similar to what one would intuitively consider a uniform scattering of points in a disk; in particular, the problem is equivalent to [circle packing in a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle).

Comment: K and N are uniformly distributed?